# Set different download directory based on file size or format

Tags: macos, google-chrome

How can I make Google Chrome automatically set the default download directory based on a set of rules involving file size and format? For example, I would like to save big files (>1Gb) to another volume so the hourly snapshot on the system volume does not include this file which I will not need permanently (space concerns).

Answer (score 0):

This Chrome extension ([Download Location Controller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-location-control/ffblgjnocedmidbaeignfilgnhikfdbc)) allows you to save files in different folders depending on the file extension.

Comment: This only allows me to save files based on file extension, but not file size.